# How to Model user-custom Table model relation to Field model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm building a CMS and one of the features I would like to add is user-specified pseudo-tables, to let users with sufficient permissions create tables, columns, rows, and fields. Obviously, for security reasons letting them actually access the database is ill-advised, so I'm looking at creating a Tables model and associated sub-models (Column, Row, Field). Here is the schema I am currently looking at:

```
UserTable:
- id:int
- title:string
- :has_many UserColumns
- :has_many UserRows
- :has_many UserFields :through => rows

UserColumn:
- id:int
- table_id:int (foreign key)
- title:string
- type:enum
- :belongs_to UserTable
- :has_many UserFields

UserRow:
- id:int
- table_id:int (foreign key)
- :belongs_to UserTable
- :has_many UserFields

UserField:
- id:int
- row_id:int (foreign key)
- column_id:int (foreign key)
- data:string
```

The big question I am still confronting is on the `UserTable` -> `UserField` relation. It looks like that can either run through `UserColumn` or through `UserRow`. The latter feels more intuitive to me, so that's what I'm currently using, but if there's a good reason to go either way, I'd like to hear it. Likewise if there are any critical issues that I'm not seeing, or just an easier way to approach the whole mess (although this seems to be reasonably simple).

Answer (score 1):

I would go using schemes, depending on how many users are involved. It is fairly easy to create a new scheme with a new user, and then to create the tables needed.

With full schemes you can control access on a very fine granularity, provide for easy and secure back-up and data migration etc.

Why haven't you considered using schemes on the first place?

Comment: Mostly for CYA reasons. A comparable feature to what I am trying to build would be SharePoint's custom lists, if that helps clarify what I am looking to build here.

Comment: Even then. You can allow the user to create his/her own custom tables in the protected space of schemes. And you would still be in control of it.  Just append the scheme name with a user identifier, like its login or id.